# Updating + SystemUpdate()

Tags: event-receivers, updatelistitems

I need to execute the SystemUpdate(true) in the event "UPDATING" to get the new item version field value.

How can I do that without receive the message of conflict?

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
...
...
properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();
```

getting error here!

Answer (score 0):

There could many issues there. For example, are you disabling the event firing first?

> this.DisableEventFiring();
>   or
>   EventFiringEnabled = false;

It would be best to post your relevant code here if it is not too long (or remove the really unnecessary parts)